# Installing EPSON L355 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the driver of my printer from [here](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-L355_Series) because in the "printers" drivers menu the driver for EPSON L355 does not appear.

When I try to install the drivers I get this error

```
vladimir@qubit:~/Documents/Programs/epson_printer_drivers$ sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package epson-inkjet-printer-201207w.
(Reading database ... 215943 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-201207w (1.0.0-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-201207w:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201207w depends on lsb (>= 3.2).

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-201207w (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-201207w
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried some solutions involving the package alien, as well as gdebi, but I can't succeed. I'm a bit desperate by now, so any help is very much appreciated.

Also, checking my lsb gives:

```
vladimir@qubit:~/Documents/Programs/epson_printer_drivers$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-amd64:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-amd64:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-amd64:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-amd64:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-amd64:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-amd64:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: I had this problem back when 14.04 LTS was first released, then I switched from distro but came back on a new computer and Ubuntu install with 16.04 LTS. Not using this exact model but L455 and Epson drivers work OK now.

Comment: @xangua thanks but I decided to stick with ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If that's your choice you could try  opening the .deb file, search and extract the .PPD file to use it (you should be offer this option when setting a printer if no drivers are found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP accidentally tried to install 32bit driver, while using a 64bit OS.

- [32bit driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-i386/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb)
- [64bit driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb)

OP installed the 64bit driver, and all was resolved.

Comment: I get exactly the same error :(

Comment: What about running `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: I've already done it, and if I run `sudo dpkg -i epson...`, the error appears again.

Comment: Can you run `lsb_release -a` please?

Comment: The output is too long, so I appended it to the question

Comment: Is it possible to install `sudo apt-get install lsb:i386`?

Comment: No installation candidate: `Package lsb:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lsb-core:i386 lsb-core lsb-base` when I tried to install them I got a message saying that the packages are already in their newest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49165/discussion-between-thatguy-and-vladimir-vargas).

Comment: Ok, edited to show the driver versions.  @VladimirVargas - Hope that helps!